# Make a dict of list of lists from dict of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a `dict`

```py
context = {
           "x":["col1", "col2", "col3"], 
           "a":["val1","val2","val3"], 
           "b":["val4","val5","val6"]
          }
```

And I would like to convert it something like this

```py
context = {
           "x":["col1", "col2", "col3"], 
           "data":[["val1","val2","val3"], ["val4","val5","val6"]]
          }
```

How Could I achieve this?

Comment: `context = {'x': context['x'], 'data': [context['a'], context['b']]}`

Comment: If `context` is always like this (same keys especially), simply do what @Rahul K P said. Otherwise you'll have to be a bit more specific about the shape of you inputs and what you want.

Comment: @RahulKP or simply change `context` in-place: `context['data'] = [context.pop('a'), context.pop('b')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the data from your dict, put them in a list, then add the list to your dict.

```py
context = {
           "x":["col1", "col2", "col3"],
           "a":["val1","val2","val3"],
           "b":["val4","val5","val6"]
          }

data = [context.pop("a"), context.pop("b")]
context["data"] = data
```

Comment: I just though about it, and edited to simplify accordingly.